# How to share LibGDX screenshot to Facebook using FB Android API?

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx, facebook-android-sdk

I want to share libGDX screen to Facebook using Facebook Android SDK. My code is:

*AndroidLauncher.java*

```
if (!fbLoggedin()) fbLogin();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
  .addPhoto(new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(Utils.takeScreenShot(graphics.getView()))
    .build())
  .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
    .setHashtag("#enibo")
    .build())
  .build();
shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

*Utils.java*

```
class Utils {
    ...
    public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        if(view.getDrawingCache() == null) return null;
        Bitmap snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return snapshot;
    }
}
```

But I only see a black image on the Facebook Share Dialog. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I once did something like this. Here are the code snippets I used.

**Define the view**

```
screenshot = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.screenshot);
screenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

**Take this method to create Bitmap of your view**

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getMeasuredWidth(),v.getMeasuredHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

**Then save to storage and use it (see uri)**

```
try {
    loadBitmapFromView(screenshot)
            .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                    100,
                    new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg"));
```

Comment: Sorry. But it doesn't work. Because libgdx uses glsurfaceview which is transparent. (you can't draw a transparent view to the bitmap).